# how do i set custom date in android

Tags: android

How do i set the date to 25 -12(december)- current year.
eg.

I am using this code

```
public static Calendar defaultCalendar() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.add(Calendar.YEAR,0);
    currentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
    currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE,25);
    return currentDate;
}
```

Comment: what problem you are getting in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 public static Calendar defaultCalendar() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.set(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),Calendar.DECEMBER,25);
    return currentDate;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to *add* 12 months, instead of *setting* the month to December (which is month 11, because the Java API is horrible). You want something like:

```
public static Calendar defaultCalendar() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // Months are 0-based!
    currentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25); // Clearer than DATE
    return currentDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it found very usefull to me though :

Take a look at `SimpleDateFormat`.

The basics for getting the current time in ISO8601 format:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

For other formats:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    String now = df.format(new Date());
```

or

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

**EDit:**

Check this link it will help you :

[Specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700285/android-how-to-set-an-alarm-to-a-specific-date)

Comment: I don't see any indication in the question that the OP wants a string representation...

Comment: im new bee in droid,i dont want formate,just my question is how do i set the date picker date to 25 december n current year

Comment: see edited link it 's like this : Use cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER)