# Preselect the user selected date on calendar

Tags: android

I want to set the custom date on caleder.present i am showing the current date,now i want to show the existing date.how to set custom date on calender?

I am using the following code.

```
 DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                    }
                }, year, month, year);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dpd.show();
```

Comment: You had a look over [here ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7661830/3282633)

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor, this line:

```
}, year, month, year);
```

I don't know why you have two year, but second year is acctually `dayOfMonth` look into documentation:

> DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)

If you want change default date of date picker change this 3 variables, year, month and dayOfMonth to set specific date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the update method

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();   

now.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 

int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // it's zero based
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePicker datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);
```

Check on official documentation of android [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29)