# developing a scheduled application in android

Tags: android

i want to make a scheduled application in android , for example set a date and time and when these date  and time reached a sound file will be played .. what is the possible ways to help me to achieve this

thanks
Sherif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible way is to use `AlarmManager`
Have a look at the `AlarmManager` in android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

`AlarmManager alarmManager =
                    (AlarmManager)
                    this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);`

Comment: Thanks for reply , but how to set the AlarmManager to be triggered in a specific date and time , because the all examples i saw it takes time in milliseconds and no date ..

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700285/android-how-to-set-an-alarm-to-a-specific-date