# set alarm notification between two specific date with particular day in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

Hello friends i want to set notification with two specific dates like

**date1= 2014/10/30**

**date2=2015/10/30**

and alarm should be notify at every **5th day(means date=5)** of every month until **date2**.

how can i achieve this any idea Thanks in advances?

Comment: Hello...did u solve this problem..if so pls help me too...